# How to write numbers(float and int) in a text

Tags: c#

I just code a program that write in a .txt file but it just write strings. Im using the List.add

```
string filePath = @"C:\openner\text.txt";

List<string> lines = new List<string>();
lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

lines.Add("lucros do mes:");
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

Im using the Add to add the informations in the .txt file but it does not add int or float, just strings

Comment: you can use string concatenation e.g. `"text "+12+" text again "+4.3` or use `String.Format`. Did you try this?

Comment: You have a `List<string>`... Why would you expect to be able to add anything but strings to that?

Comment: If you write to a file that contains text, then you need to write, well, text. Your `int` and `float` can be *converted* with, e.g., `[int].ToString()` Or `$"Some text and {IntValue}"` etc.. What is the purpose, just storage? You can serialize these values, strings and others, to a JSON file, using a class model that describes the values to serialize/deserialize. Much easier to handle. When you deserialize, you get back the original values in their original form.

Comment: You cant do that on a string List elliot, you must create methods that will return the sum of the converted values.

Comment: thank u guys i already have see my mistake and i changing. Thanks for the support.

Comment: fixed up, now it is working as expected, thank u guys